# How to write a fallback for css files not loaded, loading too long and blocked?

Tags: javascript, css, cdn, conditional-statements, fallback

I am trying to write a conditional statement for my css files, because I am hoping to host them on CDN. Anyhow, I need to write a fallback for it, so if the CDN encountered a possible downtime, I could run the file right away on my own server. The problem is my knowledge of writing javascript is still a beginner, therefore I have no idea how to write the script.

Can anybody please help me out on this?

The piece code below is one I hope to use upon CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/animate.min.css">
```

Please educate me on how may I create this conditional function properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Seems like all of these very kind people have marked your question as a *duplicate*, however they didn't notice that the answer provided to that question does not work (the answer is from **2011** for god's sake, see why it doesn't work in the notes). I've already flagged it to moderators to see if they can unmark that.

Anyways, I've created a [**new demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t4t1fu62/) for my updated answer taking into consideration your need to check for multiple cdn css files and how that may affect your websites performance. (I've used the `head` method in the `XMLHttpRequest()` which is faster according to [**this cool guy**](https://ochronus.com/http-head-request-good-uses/) since it doesn't retrieve the pages body.

Also I've provided a format to easily replace failed *external* `<link>` tags which their *local* counterpart.

### JavaScript

```
CSSback = {
    local: "cssfallback/",
    fallbacks: {
        "animate.min.css": "localanimate.css",
        "nonexistent.min.css": "localnonexistent.css"
    }
}

CSSback.init = function () {
    var links = document.head.querySelectorAll("link");
    for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        this.ping(link);
    }
}.bind(CSSback);

CSSback.ping = function (link) {
    var url = link.href;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status != 200) this.fallback(link);
    }.bind(this);
    http.open("head", url, true);
    http.send();
}.bind(CSSback);

CSSback.fallback = function (link) {
    var url = link.href.split("/");
    var name = url[url.length - 1];
    var fallback = this.fallbacks[name];
    if (fallback) {
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
        var link = document.createElement("link");
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.href = this.local + fallback;
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }
}.bind(CSSback);

window.addEventListener("load", CSSback.init);
```

### Usage

You should modify the `CSSBack{}`'s `local` (for the path to the local stylesheets) and `fallbacks` (for a key-value relationship between the name of the *external* stylesheet, and the name of the *local* stylesheet).

#### HTML

```
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/animate.min.css" (..) >
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/nonexistent.min.css" (..) >
```

#### Modified JavaScript

```
CSSback = {
    local: "cssfallback/",
    fallbacks: {
        "animate.min.css": "localanimate.css",
        "nonexistent.min.css": "localnonexistent.css"
    }
}
```

If any `<link>` fails, it will remove it and replace it with it's local counterpart, in this case `nonexistent.min.css` will fail and it will be replaced leaving the final `<link>` tags being:

```
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.2.0/animate.min.css" (..) >
<link href="cssfallback/nonexistent.css" (..) >
```

### Notes

- A `<link>` will fail if it's response status is **0** (non-allowed) or **404** (not-found), that means if the stylesheet is online but it's server doesn't have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"` policy it will think it failed too. (Fortunately most cdn's have it, including yours).
- The selected answer in the other question does not work because `document.styleSheets.cssRules` in external stylesheets returns `null` in Chrome and Firefox just bluntly throws you a Security Error.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Rou. Very detailed and helpful explanation. It educates me a bit in the server side of programming too. I will keep this in my list of techniques. Anyhow, would this affect my web performance if I was to write this script for every CDN linked? I'm also wondering if a fallback is actually really needed when CDN has some many other servers, so they could run on another one when one's down?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it as fast as possible and to easily implementate more than one cdn link, but in my personal opinion, the only reason why a cdn hosted file would be down it's if they removed it from there servers manually ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!! You're amazing help. Yes, I got very upset when I saw the down vote and marked as duplicate comments... I read all the other similar questions and their so long ago and I don't quite seem to understand them ... I thought I was just too naive, haha. :D So thank you for the answer. Big help. Would recommend others to read it too! Loved the demo as well!!! ;D

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :) (pd:You can mark your question as answered by clicking on the green tick next to the answer)